# Check Supported Platforms for Editor

Tags: unity, c#, build-process

How can I find out from script(c#) did I download specific platfrom support for current Unity version?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context about what you're doing that needs to query this information from script?

Comment: Just wanted to add that Unity has made this method public i e: [BuildPipeline.IsTargetPlatformSupported][1] [1]:https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.IsBuildTargetSupported.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution. You should dive in into Unity native classes and get info from there:

```
        var moduleManager = System.Type.GetType("UnityEditor.Modules.ModuleManager,UnityEditor.dll");
        var isPlatformSupportLoaded = moduleManager.GetMethod("IsPlatformSupportLoaded", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var getTargetStringFromBuildTarget = moduleManager.GetMethod("GetTargetStringFromBuildTarget", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        return (bool)isPlatformSupportLoaded.Invoke(null, new object[] { (string)getTargetStringFromBuildTarget.Invoke(null, new object[] { BuildTarget.tvOS }) });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install Unity , you can choose from a list of supported "build" platform:

- Windows
- Max
- iOS
- Android

and so on.

So you can build specific platform.

You can't check it from C#.

Comment: Could you use the scriptable build pipeline to try to kick off a build of a trivial/empty project om each platform, and trap the ones that generate an error? Not an efficient method by any means, but might not be impossible.